# Thymeleaf get current url without base url

Tags: java, spring, url, thymeleaf

Is there a way in thymeleaf to get current url's portion after the base url and use it as a string for example in `th:text`?

Example: `http://www.example.com/payment-page/pay` I want the `/payment-page/pay` or `payment-page/pay` portion. Thanks.

Comment: I would try using {#httpServletRequest.requestURI} to get the full URL and then implement a simple function to remove the base URL from the string. Depending on your requirements you could also do this on the server side and pass the relative URL as a string variable to your view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use this :

```
<span th:with="url=${#httpServletRequest.requestURI}"/>
<span th:text="${url}"></span>
```

examle  output payment-page/pay for this url http://www.example.com/payment-page/pay.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone searching on this, this answer no longer works with Thymeleaf 3.1.

I had the same issue. This is what I did:

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackageClasses = AdminControllersPackage.class)
public class AdminControllerAdvice {

    @ModelAttribute("requestURI")
    String getRequestServletPath(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getServletPath();
    }

}
```

The `AdminControllersPackage` class is just a marker class which I used so the ControllerAdvice would only apply to controllers in the relevant package. It's an empty definition:

```
final class AdminControllerPackage { 
   private AdminControllerPackage() { throw new RuntimeException(); } 
}
```

If you want this to apply to all controllers in your application, you can omit that.

Then you can access `requestURI` like any other variable in your templates:

```
<p>The URI is: [[${requestURI}]]</p>
```

It's actually nice to do things this way, because more often I want to do some logic based on the URI and my ControllerAdvice could do a lot more in Java than I can practically put in a Thymeleaf expression.